# JS removeEventListener with function inside

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I've created a function search with an event listener on a button. The problem is that the removeEventListener isn't working because init() is inside it to execute. Thus the EventListener is replicated everytime I click the button. If I remove init() all is fine. Maybe i misunderstand someting about it?

Also if i remove the function search and only use const I know it fires ones. But the whole point is that i need to use search.

```
function search(data) {
  const clickHandler = () => {
   console.log('search');

   init();
 };

 document.getElementById('search').removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

search(data);

function init() {
 console.log('hello');
}

console results:
first time; hello
second time; hello hello
third time; hello hello hello hello
```

Comment: Problem is the fact you are trying to remove a different function than the one that was added. has nothing to do with init. When you call search, it makes a new function. It is not the same function that was created the previous time you called it.

Comment: I highly doubt that is true because my code in my answer below does not use init and has same exact problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is scoping. When you put the function inside another, it is scoped to that function. So next time you call the function, you create a new function. So you are trying to remove a function that did not exist before.

```js
function clickHandler2() {
  console.log('world');
}


function search() {
  const clickHandler = () => {
   console.log('hello');
 };

 document.getElementById('search').removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
 
 document.getElementById('search').removeEventListener('click', clickHandler2);
 document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', clickHandler2);
}

search();
search();
search();
```

```html
<button type="button" id="search">Search</button>
```

Comment: Now I get it. it's scoped to init. Well back to the drawing board then.